# How to make unique relationship between two table in Power Bi on left part of text

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

As a rookie in Power Bi, Power Query and Dax **I am stuck on how to make up a unique relationship between two tables when only left part of my key is known.**

The first table is a result unique values of user inputs from one of the It systems.

I managed to add a column here that can calculate the Actual cost on all orders based on the left part of the WBS_ELEMENT like this:

```
Actual Cost = SUMX (FILTER ('SAP Orders', LEFT('SAP Orders'[WBS_ELEMENT], LEN([WBS in Uppercase])) = [WBS in Uppercase]),'SAP Orders'[ACTUAL_COSTS])
```

**Question 1:** How can I **filter** this **Sap Order** table in **Power Query** on the unique values by the left part of the WBS_ELEMENT? Note that the first table changes all the time, and it will grow in time. That means it need to filter on all values that BeginsWith.

**Question 2:** How can I make a **unique relationship** column in Sap Order table to be used as the relations when filtering is applied?

I have tried several ways to create the relation column like  = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Match", each Text.Equals([WBS_ELEMENT], uWBS[Used_WBS])) without any luck.

Example of my problem and some table values here:
[image: Distinct_ERP_PROJECT_ID]

The second table is of SAP Orders, and is quite large. The best would be if I could use the first table to filter out numbers of records in Power Query, so I can select more columns and reduce my dataset a lot. But I can`t find a good solution here either to filter on the left part of these unique input values.

[image: SAP Orders]

Description of my problem:
Column Used_WBS is added to the table in Power Query M - and is to be used as the unique relations on any given WBS in the Distinct_ERP_PROJECT_ID table.

Why is Used_WBS = null on SS-B33813-30-A-08-06-100 as the only order containing the full WBS path ?

According to the first answer I have tried:

```
MergeWBS = Table.AddColumn(#"Kilde", "Join", each Table.SelectRows(Distinct_ERP_PROJECT_ID, (uWBS) => Text.StartsWith(_[WBS_ELEMENT]&"x", uWBS[Used_WBS], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
```

and without the &"x" (added just to check if Text.StartsWith return false if equal). I have also tried this:

```
MergeWBS = Table.AddColumn(Kilde, "Join", each Table.SelectRows(Distinct_ERP_PROJECT_ID, (uWBS) => Text.PositionOf(_[WBS_ELEMENT], uWBS[Used_WBS], Occurrence.First, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Question 1**
In PowerQuery, in your `SAP Orders` query, in Advanced Editor, add the following steps: (replace << ... >> bits)

```
  MergeWBS = Table.AddColumn(<<PreviousStep>>, "Join", each Table.SelectRows(<<Unique WBS Query>>, (uWBS) => Text.StartsWith(_[WBS_ELEMENT], uWBS[Used_WBS], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
  #"Expanded WBS" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeWBS , "Join", {"Used_WBS"}, {"Used_WBS"})
in
  #"Expanded WBS"
```

This should give you a new column in your `SAP Orders` query of the matched "Used_WBS".

**For Question 2**
With the above, you can now create a relationship between the two tables.

**Additional - for demo**
In a new PBIX, create a query for each of the below with their respective query name in the comment. (To this in the same order).

```
// SAP Orders
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("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", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [WBS_ELEMENT = _t, #"ACTUAL_COSTS -" = _t, #"ACTUAL_HOURS -" = _t, #"ORDER NUMBER" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"WBS_ELEMENT", type text}, {"ACTUAL_COSTS -", Int64.Type}, {"ACTUAL_HOURS -", Int64.Type}, {"ORDER NUMBER", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Stop Folding" = Table.StopFolding(#"Changed Type")
in
    #"Stop Folding"

// WBS
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("dVLLbsQwCPyXnEHiZcDH7kr9gRxXe+on5P+lOvHGcaT2NniGETB+vZZ1xYcYW0VSZCRe4M+35Q1drJqsqIRfSInkyESfnn8oyUwHkcnCXUdPx1WVazoD+6l7PihKdN3Ag1ypuX7IE7NpGEgcom3bieAcoo5ZS1KBqjermKx2zBJm08SlELqMoUdZSooK8M2t1svtwPPq0u6iGPid1wlubzXYSwHjc42fjVKvNTrer2Vgk6ae4TVNvYW2N8VkcGAVMYd6xSLq1CKP8wdcpbiZC0SL5v0L", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Used_WBS = _t, #"WBS in Uppercase -" = _t, #"Actual Cost -" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Used_WBS", type text}, {"WBS in Uppercase -", type text}, {"Actual Cost -", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Stop Folding" = Table.StopFolding(#"Changed Type")
in
    #"Stop Folding"

// SAP Orders w StartsWith
let
    Source = #"SAP Orders",
    MergeWBS = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Join", each Table.SelectRows(WBS, (uWBS) => Text.StartsWith([WBS_ELEMENT], uWBS[Used_WBS], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),
  #"Expanded WBS" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeWBS , "Join", {"Used_WBS"}, {"Used_WBS"})
in
  #"Expanded WBS"

// SAP Orders w Position
let
    Source = #"SAP Orders",
    MergeWBS = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Join", each Table.SelectRows(WBS, (uWBS) => Text.PositionOf([WBS_ELEMENT], uWBS[Used_WBS], Occurrence.First, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0)),
  #"Expanded WBS" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeWBS , "Join", {"Used_WBS"}, {"Used_WBS"})
in
  #"Expanded WBS"
```

Comment: That actually worked (at least in Power Query) - But the numbers of records seams to have increased in abundance. I had to stop the update of SAP Orders when numbers of records passed 10 millions. The Sap Order table is less than 957 000 rows now. And I even added a extra step to filter and remove all the 'Null' values from this table before I hit the Save & Load. Any idea of why this happened?

Comment: I now let it run out and finish loading, as I figured out that 14 values times 1 million is 14 millions join tests.  It ended ended up with only 1471 records. So I need to do some kind of filtering first in my SQL where statement. My problem in Power Query is that there is no easy way to add any dynamic where statement with a reference to values in this Used WBS table.

Comment: Look into Query Folding (mainly preventing query folding) https://powerquery.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/stop-query-folding-with-table-stopfolding/ You definitely want Power BI to do the join and not for it to fold back to SQL

Comment: It also left out the one equal to the full WBS like 'SS-B33813-30-A-08-06-100' that also returned Null (and later excluded by filtering the Null values)

Comment: That is odd as Text.StartsWith should also return TRUE if both parts are equal. Is it possible there are any leading/trailing spaces? Did this happen without Query Folding?

Comment: Yes - When I reduced my query to just pick up this WBS I only got this one record of orders. Was done just to check the result in Power Query before Loading all data.  I have also tried to insert a filter step like this:
#"Filtrerte rader1" = Table.SelectRows(Kilde, each try List.Contains(#"Distinct_ERP_PROJECT_ID"[Used_WBS],[Used_WBS]) otherwise null),

Comment: Did you try disabling Query Folding? Add a step to both your table queries, just after you get the data from SQL - `PreventQueryFolding = Table.StopFolding( <previousStep>  )`

Comment: Tried disabling Query Folding - with no luck. 'Groundhog day' once more. Tested the Fuzzy join as well, but that takes the same amount of time to update the table like 4-5 minutes do to the inner join it needs to perform. Maybe it is better to make this new column in Power Bi DAX in stead and find another way to reduce the amount of order records. I have teste several types of SQL in my souse file to create the same table and used it for this inner join that takes the 1 million records down to prox. 4500.

Comment: Shame. Wish I could dive in and figure this out with you more.

Comment: Can we test Text.StartsWith with two equal values?

Comment: Yes, in Powerquery, but I'm not sure how this folds back to SQL (if folding). Might be `Like "XYZ+"` or hopefully `Like "XYZ*"`, right click on the step and see Native Query

Comment: Bing AI says. Text.StartsWith does not have a bug. It is designed to return False when the two strings are equal, because it only checks if the first string starts with the second string, not if they are the same. This is different from the Text.Contains function, which returns True if the first string contains the second string anywhere, including at the beginning. For example, Text.Contains ("abc", "abc") returns True, but Text.Contains ("abc", "ab") also returns True, because the first string contains the second string at the beginning.

Comment: `Text.StartsWith("hello", "hello", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` = TRUE on my machine. Regardless, swap it with: `Text.PositionOf(_[WBS_ELEMENT], uWBS[Used_WBS], Occurrence.First, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = 0`

Comment: It returns Null with this as well. I have also tried to add an extra character like this Text.StartsWith(_[WBS_ELEMENT]&"x", uWBS[Used_WBS] as Bing AI relied return false if equal. And even tried Text.Equal with no luck on just this one join. I will try to add some portions of these tables in a Excel file and update the question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is no `Text.Equals` function. You're losing me. I can provide a sample PBIX with the above if you supply me the test data in the screen shots in your question. Try `Text.Upper([WBS_ELEMENT]) = Text.Upper(uWBS[Used_WBS]) or Text.StartsWith(...)`

Comment: See this sample .PBIX https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtpcKzRsDrY1o7U4B2HGU01T_nQbew?e=bohhIw

Comment: Same result with this :
MergeWBS = Table.AddColumn(#"Kilde", "Join", each Table.SelectRows(Distinct_ERP_PROJECT_ID, (uWBS) => Text.Upper([WBS_ELEMENT]) = Text.Upper(uWBS[Used_WBS]) or Text.StartsWith(_[WBS_ELEMENT], uWBS[Used_WBS], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),

Comment: Please explain what "same result" means. Did you see the sample PBIX I provided two comments up?

Comment: My organization don`t allow me to open your pbix file - even after it has been downloaded. Groundhog day, once more. Same result means that the join is always returning null on the one order record with the full WBS present. But if I skip filtering in Power Query, and rather use the DAX in Power Bi to make this new column, it might work. But then I need to find some other way to reduce my orders table.

Comment: No worries, I have updated the answer above with the **Additional** section at the bottom. Create a new PBIX, and re-create those 4 queries via Blank Query & Advanced Editor.

Comment: Finally - I will accept this as the answer  - Thanks al lot. It looks like the #"Stop Folding" = Table.StopFolding(#"Changed Type") step did the trick along with a new table based on the SAP order table. I will implement the same split in my model.

Comment: Phew! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was actually solved early on by Sam Nseir, but it was very hard to actually spot all the spaces at the end.

The temporary solution was to add a step to trim the Used_WBS column. Right Click on the column and select Transform - Trim made up this step to clean up the input data.

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Stop Folding",{{"Used_WBS", Text.Trim, type text}})
```

Used_WBS is here a result of user inputs. So the one record I had my trouble with I copied the value and pasted it into Notepad. Where you can mark and se the blanks values as well.

[image: Whitespaces]

**Answer to Question 1**

Perform a inner join with use of **LIKE CONCAT(B.WBS, '%')** on the source file in SQL, to reduce the amount of orders records, and perform the trim of the district WBS values. My Order query now looks like this:

```
    SELECT WBS_ELEMENT, ACTUAL_COSTS, ACTUAL_HOURS, ORDER_NUMBER, ACTUAL_RELEASE_DATE
FROM [[Our_Warehouse]].SERVICE_ORDER_HEADER AS A
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT trim(ERP_PROJECT_ID) as WBS FROM [[Our_Warehouse]].SERVICE_PROJECT_COST_ITEM_DATA WHERE ERP_PROJECT_ID <> '') AS B
ON A.WBS_ELEMENT LIKE CONCAT(B.WBS, '%')
```

The final solution was to make our developers to perform this trim of ERP_PROJECT_ID and switch to uppercase already in the app developed to takes this input field. Always best to clean up data before it reaches the data warehouse.

**Answer to Question 2**

Like described in accepted answer with these steps:

```
#"Stop Folding" = Table.StopFolding(#"Changed Type"),

MergeWBS = Table.AddColumn(#"Stop Folding", "Join", each Table.SelectRows(WBS, (uWBS) => Text.StartsWith([WBS_ELEMENT], uWBS[Used_WBS], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))),

#"Expanded WBS" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeWBS , "Join", {"Used_WBS"}, {"Used_WBS"}),
```